# Can one CMake target link against a *shared* version of another library target?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project with a core library (`LibA` in the example below), an executable, and a second library (`LibB`) that depends on the first library.  The second library (`LibB`) is always built in shared (dynamic library) form.

Is there any way that I can force `LibB` to *always* link against the *shared* version of `LibA`?

Here is a small `CMakeLists.txt` file illustrating the problem:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(my_project LANGUAGES CXX)

# LibA should be buildable in either static or shared form.
add_library(LibA A.cpp)
# In the real case, there are many customizations to `LibA`: 
# compile flags, include dirs, target properties, etc.

add_executable(ExecutableA main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ExecutableA LibA)

# I want library myB to *always* link against the dynamic library libLibA.so.
add_library(LibB SHARED B.cpp)
target_link_libraries(LibB PUBLIC LibA m pthread)
```

It can be built with the following commands:

```
echo 'int main() {}' > main.cpp
touch A.cpp B.cpp
mkdir -p build 
cmake -B build/ -S .
cmake --build build/
```

I know that I can force `LibA` to be always shared with `add_library(LibA SHARED A.cpp)`, but I want to be able to build `LibA` as a static library.

The real context for this is that I have a core library (`LibA`), and want to link against it statically when creating executables, but link against it dynamically (as `LibA.so`) when creating a Python extension module (`LibB.so`).

Comment: `want to link against it statically when creating executables, but link against it dynamically (as LibA.so) when creating a Python extension module (LibB.so).` so you have __two__ libraries, not one - one library is static and the another is shared.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I would have one library *target* or *definitions* in the CMake build system, and multiple output files in the CMAKE_BINARY_DIR corresponding to that target, yes.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible, `libA` can only be either static or dynamic, not both.

You need to have two versions of `libA`, one dynamic, one static:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(my_project LANGUAGES CXX)

function( addLibA suffix type )

    set( libname LibA${suffix} )
    add_library(${libname} ${type} A.cpp)

    # specify library properties here

endfunction()

# LibA should be buildable in either static or shared form.
addLibA("s" STATIC)
addLibA("" SHARED)
# In the real case, there are many customizations to `LibA`: 
# compile flags, include dirs, target properties, etc.

add_executable(ExecutableA main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ExecutableA LibAs)

# I want library myB to *always* link against the dynamic library libLibA.so.
add_library(LibB SHARED B.cpp)
target_link_libraries(LibB PUBLIC LibA m pthread)
```

Comment: A single library *target* can be built in static or dynamic form, depending on the value of `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`. Are you saying that after configuration, a library target can only be built in one way?

Comment: This approach would require that a user define all properties of the library twice: once for `LibA` and once for `libAs`.

Comment: @NicholasM: `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` is a global option that will make all libraries be built as shared. If set, only libraries specifically specified to be static will be static. But this does not change the fact that LibA will be either static or dynamic, cannot be both.

Comment: @NicholasM: For properties, you can do it once only if you create a functon to be used in both cases. See edited answer.

Answer (score 5):

What you are specifically asking for will require multiple targets, as has been mentioned in comments / jpo38's answer

However you might be interested in using CMake's [Object Libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) instead to share the objects between a library target and an executable target. For example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(my_project LANGUAGES CXX)

# Objects get built exactly once
add_library(LibA.objects OBJECTS 
  A.cpp
)
target_compile_commands( ... )
target_include_directories( ... )

# Shared library for libA
add_library(LibA SHARED
  $<OBJECTS:LibA.objects>
)

# LibB -- always shared, always linked against dynamic LibA
add_library(LibB SHARED
  B.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(LibB PUBLIC LibA)

# ExecutableA, built using LibA's objects 
# (effectively the same linking a static LibA.a)
add_executable(ExecutableA
  main.cpp
  $<OBJECTS:LibA.objects>
)
```

Using an object library, your objects get built once, but are shared between multiple targets. Using multiple library targets, on the other hand, will force a rebuild of each object, since each target may use different compile commands.

This allows `ExecutableA` to have `LibA`'s objects built into it, so it behaves effectively as though you had statically linked in a `LibA.a`.
In this case, `LibA` is now built as a `SHARED` library explicitly, since this is desired for `LibB` to dynamically link against.

If you're using newer versions of CMake, you can also avoid the `$<OBJECTS:...>` generator expression, and just link against the object library directly with `target_link_libraries` -- e.g.:

```
target_link_libraries(libA PRIVATE LibA.objects)
...
target_link_libraries(ExecutableA PRIVATE LibA.objects)
```

---

This approach will also allow properties to be applied *once* to their respective targets. Any properties regarding the sourcefiles themselves just needs to apply directly to the Object library. Any properties regarding the library setup/layout (e.g. output location, suffixes, etc) applies strictly to the library targets.